# Use 'filter' from the Controller in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

Please review this fiddle. I am trying to use 'filter' from the controller. I have an data array, which i want to search based on the search criteria provided in the text box attached with the button.

User enters text and then press enters to search.
User presses the back key on the text box the original list appears again.

I want to apply the filter from the controller and not on my partial. So i have to work with what i have.

Please advice.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type='text' data-ng-model='search'>
    <button ng-click='newList()'> </button>
        <table> <tr data-ng-repeat= "item in items"><td> {{item.name}}  </td></tr></table>    

    </div>
</div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.items= [
    {
    id: 0,
    name: "Noman",
    email: "John@email.com"},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Sameer",
    email: "James@email.com"},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Humair",
    email: "Jill@email.com"}
];    

$scope.newList =  function () {
$scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items,'name',$scope.search)
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7KH7/66/

Comment: $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items,$scope.search,true)

This line should be like this i guess. But how to make the list appear back if they take out the text from the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter based on an object property by passing an object with the property that you need the filter on and the value based on which the filter needs to be applied.

So, in your case, the filter parameter is:

```
{
    name: $scope.search
}
```

You can then use this in your controller as:

```
$scope.newList = function () {
    $scope.newItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items,{name: $scope.search})
};
```

Note - you need to use a different array to display in the view and not the original array because after the filter is applied, you still want the old contents to filter with new values.

This means, that in your view, instead of using the original item list `$scope.items` use `$scope.newItems` in the `ng-repeat` directive.

See Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4yRv/

Comment: Makes sense, but how i can make the original array appear again when the user clears the search text box, [using backspace] without pressing the search button.

Comment: If the user simply presses backspace, then you can't reset the search AND still allow filter only on clicking button. What you can do however is show the filter when the contents are completely erased. Just `$scope.$watch()` the model on the input and when it is empty, reset the search.

Comment: Got it. $watch will check if there is a change in $scope.search and then i can call an event on that, which will be the original list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need an additional array, containing the filtered items, and you need to iterate on this.

Second, the second argument of the filter should be

```
{name: $scope.search}
```

because you want to filter the items based on their name property.

Here is your example, working: http://jsfiddle.net/r7KH7/67/